# Include Javascript into HTML

Tags: javascript

[image]

I had two folder: folder HTML hold file .html and folder Script hold file myscript.js. And now i want to include myscript.js to file .html. I try `<script src = "Script/myscript.js" type = "text/javascript">` but it not work. How can i do?

Comment: `<script src = "../Script/myscript.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: where did you put this line of code? you should put it in the header of html

Comment: I put it in header. My problem is solved. tks for all

Comment: show me the whole html please

Comment: also, put an alert('HI'); to it

Comment: actually, you can simply drag that file into your html , it will do it for you automaticlly!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to move up a directory first with ../

try:

```
<script src = "../Script/myscript.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Always remember to close your `<script>` tags with `</script>`

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I should have clarified that I was not writing out fully functional html. Edited to add the closing script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your external scripts like this:

```
<head>
   <script src = "../Script/myscript.js" type = "text/javascript"></script> // Path to script relative to your HTML file
</head>
```

OR

better way like this:

```
<body>
      .....All your HTML Goes here....
       <script src = "../Script/myscript.js" type = "text/javascript"></script> // Path to script relative to your HTML file
</body>
```

The reason being, your scripts delay/block your page from getting rendered which might give a feel of your website being slow.

The end user needs to see something on your page first, hence we always include CSS in the `<head>` and our scripts at the end of `<body>`.